# Send a null value through AJAX - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a method that would take 3 parameters, but a dillema comes by. One of the parameters has to be located on the 3rd place, but sometimes the 1st and 2nd paramaters can take a null value. So in order for the first parameter to  Not take in the 3rd value, but the 3rd parameter, I have to send in 1, or 2 `null` values.

To make this more clear, I have a method:

```
public ActionResult TurnoverPerItem(string startDate = null, string endDate = null, 
    int extra = 0) {
        //...
}
```

and a JS/JQuery function that sends a request:

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
    //....
}
```

but, now, the variable `url` can be one of the following (with all of the parameters (`startDate`, `endDate` and `extra`)):

```
path/to/action/15-09-2015/23-09-2015/0
```

or with only a `startDate` and `extra`

```
path/to/action/15-09-2015/0
```

or even just `extra`

```
path/to/action/0
```

but in the second example the parameter `endDate` would take in the value od 0 instead of `extra`, while `extra` would be `null` and in the third example, the parameter `startDate` would take in the `extra` value, while the others would be `null`.

My question would be, whether it is possible to send in a null value to the controller? ie. something like (one of the methods that I tried)

```
path/to/action/null/null/1
```

the web application is pretty robust, so there is a valid reason why the parameter `extra` has to take in 3rd place, but I really hope I won't have to go into details about that.

EDIT: the rout config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default-Date",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{startDate}/{endDate}/{extra}",
    defaults: new { controller = "reports", startDate = UrlParameter.Optional, endDate = UrlParameter.Optional, extra = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Did you consider changing the routing? In my opinion, the routing that you have is very vague.

Comment: @DPac as I said, it's sadly not an option. I'm not really the code creator, but more of a modifier. But based on what the previous programmer did, a lot of the routes are dependent on startDate and endDate being on the 1st and 2nd place.

Comment: An easy workaround would be to create a new method as an overload the method you're currently using.

Comment: @DPac Hmm, I'll try to do it that way.

Comment: temporary solution I took until I find a more permanent - maintainable solution is to put in an `if( startDate.Equals("null") ) startDate = null;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not saying this is a perfect solution, but it did solve the problem for me. So from what I've got through research, you can't pass a `null` value through a `GET` request.

What I can do, though, is send a string or a number. startDate and endDate are both string types and are usually formatted like:

```
12-09-1983 (dd-MM-yyyy) | or | 12-09-1983-13-45 (dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm)
```

While creating separate Routes is a good idea (and I'm thankful to Chetan Sharma and DPac for answering), it isn't an option due to some backend reasons that I won't go into.

What I did is simply fill in the blank spots. So if I only send in `extra`, it'll look like: `link/to/ajax/null/null/0`

If I only send in `startDate`: `link/to/ajax/12-12-2012/null/0`

Or if I'm sending  a full value, normally through: `link/to/ajax/12-12-2012/09-03/2015/0`

so ajax can also send in a `string = "null"`, the only step needed would be to test out the string and treat it as a normal null value.

```
public ActionResult TurnoverPerItem(string startDate = null, string endDate = null, 
    int extra = 0) {
        startDate = (startDate != null && startDate.Equals("null")) ? null : startDate;
        endDate = (endDate != null && endDate.Equals("null")) ? null : endDate;
        //...
}
```

and afterwards the code will continue running normally.

More info : [<Click here>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528221/sending-null-data-using-get-method)

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simple one liner answer for your question.

> Just try to create separate routing for each URL pattern.

Just try above solution, this work around will really solve your issue.

Comment: no can do, because of other methods that use similar routing. Some other method routes can just take a startDate (no extra anywhere). It did cross my mind - it just doesn't run as a solution.